# How to best stabilize uneven ceramic pots?

Tags: drainage

I'm in the process of replanting my houseplants form their old plastic pots into new fancy ceramic pots. The bottom of these pots and the surface of their saucers are quite rough and uneven, so the pots don't sit well in their saucers.

The plastic saucers have some tiny radial ridges exactly for this purpose.

[image: plastic pot saucer with ridges]

They seem to serve two purposes:

- help in the drainage, to give a little distance between the holes on the bottom of the pot and the saucer.
- let the pot sit in a more stable way, even if the bottom is rough and uneven

Even my quite uneven-bottomed pots sit well in them. However, I'd like to use the ceramic saucers. However, the ceramic saucers don't have these ridges and they themselves have a pretty uneven surface.

I'm thinking of two solutions:

1. place some gravel in-between. However, this will make the pot have its weight concentrated on small points instead of larger surfaces (exactly like it would be now due to its unevenness, even if maybe not so badly as it would have more contact points than without the gravel), won't this make it likely to crack? Might they also get displaced over time? Also, the saucer's rims aren't really tall, so I don't want to raise the pot too much, I still want to use the saucer as a water reserve if I'm away for a longer time. And the gravel might erode the paintwork, of course, of course only at a portion which is not visible, but I wonder if it might affect the watertightness.
2. draw some ridges or place many dots of hot glue. I don't know how it will hold up in a moist environment and under constant pressure.

My plants are water-loving, so most of the time I water them until the saucer is also filled, and they will absorb that water over time until the next watering.

Are there better ways to achieve my objective?

Comment: a dab of poster putty will enable a tight fit and won't wobble like stickers or hotglue can because it deforms to fit the available space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typical solution: Search for a product typically called "pot feet" and use **exactly** 3 per pot. For your specific concerns, that might require different, deeper saucers, as they are normally fairly tall - but you might find thinner ones.

To use the same saucers - cut plastic shims (perhaps 1" x 2", or 2.5 cm x 5 cm) from something heading to the trash or recycle, and stack those in exactly 3 stacks per pot just until the pot is stable, with minimal raising.

Things with 3 feet don't wobble - they may sit off-kilter, but they don't wobble.

You could also put a wick in the bottom of the pot allowing the pot to sit above the saucer on feet, while still being able to draw up water.

Comment: The plastic (or even better, rubber) feet were a great idea! If soft enough, I can use more than 3. Some old erasers come in really handy in such a situation. It is so obviously better than my original ideas, but this is the benefit of hindsight!